# How to replace href inside of <li> using jQuery

Tags: jquery, replace, html-lists, href

I am trying to convert a piece of code that is coming out out of a content holder. I need to modify the href within the `<LI>` tag using jQuery.

Currently the code looks like this:

```
<li id="ctl01_Auxiliary_Auxiliary_rptWrapper_Auxiliary_rptWrapper_rpt_ctl01_NavigationListItem" class="NavigationListItem">
    <a id="ctl01_Auxiliary_Auxiliary_rptWrapper_Auxiliary_rptWrapper_rpt_ctl01_NavigationLink" class="NavigationLink" href="/Public/Cart/Core/cart/MyCart.aspx?hkey=70255604-fa6d-48b6-874e-ddb636d4f3ed">
        <span class="nav-text">
        Cart
        <span class="cartFull">
        <span class="cartLeft cartSprite"></span>
        <span class="cartCenter cartSprite">
        <span>1</span>
        </span>
        <span class="cartRight cartSprite"></span>
        </span>
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

And I need to modify it to look like this:

```
<li id="ctl01_Auxiliary_Auxiliary_rptWrapper_Auxiliary_rptWrapper_rpt_ctl01_NavigationListItem" class="NavigationListItem">
    <a id="ctl01_Auxiliary_Auxiliary_rptWrapper_Auxiliary_rptWrapper_rpt_ctl01_NavigationLink" class="NavigationLink" href="/Public/Cart">
        <span class="nav-text">
        Cart
        <span class="cartFull">
        <span class="cartLeft cartSprite"></span>
        <span class="cartCenter cartSprite">
        <span>1</span>
        </span>
        <span class="cartRight cartSprite"></span>
        </span>
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I tried all sorts of recommendations from on this site but none have worked so far.

Comment: What is the conversion rule?

Comment: try this? $('li a').href='/Public/Cart'

Comment: _"I tried all sorts of recommendations from on this site but none have worked so far."_ Please add that to your question, so in the least we don't duplicate your efforts.

Comment: Did you even read a tiny bit of the jQuery documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $("li #ctl01_Auxiliary_Auxiliary_rptWrapper_Auxiliary_rptWrapper_rpt_ctl01_Navigat‌​ion‌​Link").attr("href", "/Public/Cart")
```

Comment: I only want to modify the LI tag that has and id of "'ctl01_Auxiliary_Auxiliary_rptWrapper_Auxiliary_rptWrapper_rpt_ctl01_NavigationLink'". Can you modify your answer to narrow this down.

Comment: @Tim then just find that element by id `$("#ctl01_Auxiliary_Auxiliary_rptWrapper_Auxiliary_rptWrapper_rpt_ctl01_Navigation‌​Link").attr("href", "/Public/Cart")`

Comment: That does not work. The id is attached to the LI tag. But I need to change the href that is nested within in the A tag. The LI tag itself does not have an href attribute.

Comment: @Timt there's only one element with that ID and that is `a`, which has a href attribute. But I changed my answer with a more specific selector